# How can I connect to a local sqlite3 database?

Tags: sqlite, sequelpro

I'm running a local node.js app on localhost:3000. It has a database named database in a file called db.sqlite. I tried to connect to the database with the host localhost:3000, but sequel pro says MySQL said: Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:3000' (0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`db.sqlite` is probably an `SQLite` database, not a MySQL database. `Sequel Pro` can only connect to MySQL databases.

For SQLite, you can try [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/), or [download SQLite 3](https://sqlite.org/). Note that Mac is shipped with sqlite3.

### Command Line SQLite

Using the `sqlite3` command line, you can open a database file

```
$ sqlite3 db.sqlite
```

List out tables and the schema

```
sqlite> .schema customers
CREATE TABLE "customers"
(
    [CustomerId] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] NVARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL,
    [LastName] NVARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
    [Company] NVARCHAR(80),
    [Address] NVARCHAR(70),
    [City] NVARCHAR(40),
    [State] NVARCHAR(40),
    [Country] NVARCHAR(40),
    [PostalCode] NVARCHAR(10),
    [Phone] NVARCHAR(24),
    [Fax] NVARCHAR(24),
    [Email] NVARCHAR(60)  NOT NULL,
    [SupportRepId] INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY ([SupportRepId]) REFERENCES "employees" ([EmployeeId]) 
        ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
CREATE INDEX [IFK_CustomerSupportRepId] ON "customers" ([SupportRepId]);
sqlite> .tables
albums          employees       invoices        playlists     
artists         genres          media_types     tracks        
customers       invoice_items   playlist_track
```

And execute SQL statement

```
sqlite> SELECT CustomerId, FirstName, Country from customers LIMIT 5;
1|Luís|Brazil
2|Leonie|Germany
3|François|Canada
4|Bjørn|Norway
5|František|Czech Republic
```

The example above is run using the [Chinook database](https://github.com/lerocha/chinook-database).